# Java text printing framework

Tags: java, printing

Is there any Java framework which helps to print text in specified `co-ordinates(x,y)`?

Comment: Do you mean print on paper as oppose to print on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Java Report Printing](http://www.netcat.li/java-report-printing-library/tutorial.html) library to achieve this. Have a look at `TextPrint`, `Insets`, and `InsetsPrint` classes for more information.

For a lower level API have a look at the [Java Print Service API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/JPSTOC.fm.html).

Answer (score 1):

For the ultimate in printing control, look at using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) and generating a PDF, that you can control the exact layout and positioning things and then print out the resulting PDF.

Comment: Does iText allow to print only text ?? I need to print text in predefine Page where Label are already define.