# Printing String To A Printer Using Java

Tags: java, printing

Can some one help me writing a simple java program that can print out strings from a printer. I saw some example on javaDocs site but all of them were very long and I couldnt even figure out which string was going to be printed because the button names, method names etc. all were the same. I dont mind if you add or do not add GUI to the program, ill figure out (May be but comments will help) myself. 
P.S. I mean the printer that prints paper

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a literal printer, something that prints paper, or a particular class in the Java API (such as PringWriter or PrintStream)?

Comment: Similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325530/java-text-printing-framework

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana I like the `Java Report Print Library` I'm going to need to make time to look at that. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("Bill printing");

```
         FileInputStream imagestream=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\DummyImage.jpg");
         DocFlavor doc=DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG;
         PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
         aset.add(new Copies(1)); 
         //aset.add(MediaSizeName.NA_5X7);
         aset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);
         aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
         Doc document = new SimpleDoc(imagestream, doc, null);
        // DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

         PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
         for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(services[i].getName());
         }
             Media[] res1 = (Media[]) services[0].getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, null, null);
         for (Media media : res1) {
             if (media instanceof MediaSizeName) {
                 MediaSizeName msn = (MediaSizeName) media;
                 MediaSize ms = MediaSize.getMediaSizeForName(msn);
                 float width = ms.getX(MediaSize.INCH);
                 float height = ms.getY(MediaSize.INCH);
                 System.out.println(media + ": width = " + width + "; height = " + height);
             }
         }
        DocPrintJob job = services[4].createPrintJob();
        job.print(document, aset);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 4 years old, but maybe someone use this simple solution:

```
String YourString = "first line \n second line \n etc.etc."; //define and set contents of your string - remember about formating with \n if you want to have it split on lines
JTextArea YourTextArea = new JTextArea(); //define new Swing JtextArea
YourTextArea.setLineWrap(true); //set line wrap for YourTextArea - this will prevent too long lines to be cut - they will be wrapaed to next line
YourTextArea.append(YourString); //append YourString to YourTextArea 
YourTextArea.print(); //this will display print dialog that will lead you to print contents of YourTextArea so in efect contents of YourString
```